# Recommendation for installing Ubuntu (or variant) on old hardware like HP Omnibook XE3

Tags: hardware

I want to install Ubuntu on an old HP-Laptop (Omnibook XE3 - Pentium III generation).

- Which Ubuntu version is appropriate?
- Is there some documentation for installation?
- Where can I download the selected Ubuntu version?

Thanks, Martin

Comment: Please add more details about the laptop, like RAM and build in processor. With most of the current desktop environments requiring hardware video acceleration and minimum requirements being bumped up constantly, I think it could get difficult to find a Ubuntu derivative that performs well.

Answer (score 1):

if your ram is less than 1Gb use lubuntu (lightweight Ubuntu) ,you can find and download any version of Ubuntu in the Official Sites : http://www.ubuntu.com/ - http://www.lubuntu.net/ and so on ... (Ubuntu Gnome - edubuntu...) they are very user friendly sites and you can find anything you want to know about the Ubuntu os there.